# Generate bill number in C# like 01/100 and then 02/100

Tags: c#, windows, invoice

I need to generate a bill number in a C# Windows application. The format would be 01/01 to 01/100, and then 02/01 to 02/100, and so on, and this bill number would be stored in the database. Can anyone help me?

I had tried to make two variables for the first half and another for the second half, but it didn't succeed.

Comment: What exactly have you tried and what is your **exact** problem? "*I can't succeed*" without any code example is not a good problem description.

Comment: Why "01/01" rather than "01/001"? It seems odd to pad it to 2 digits if you can end up with 3. I could also imagine starting with "01/00" and going up to "01/99"... but "01/100" is an odd final point for this. And as Andy says, you need to give more details of what you've tried and what went wrong.

Comment: Give some code, where value will change, like, events or methods.

Comment: Look! You got a muppet upvote.

Comment: The bill number can come to 01/001 and then 01/002 and so on as it reaches 01/100 then it will change the first two digits 02/001 and so one and once it reaches 99/100 then it should come as 100/001 and so on

Answer (score 2):

See if the code below helps you, but I am still not sure why you would need this. For using this in your program you need to get latest batch id once counter reaches 100. I am assuming few things to set the name of variable. Please ignore if not applicable.

```
int batchId = 1;   
while(Console.ReadLine()!= "stop")//Replace this getting latest batch id, until then use this for getting code
{
  for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i ++ )
  {
  Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}", batchId, i.ToString("00"));
  }
  batchId++;
}
```